# ASCII - Whats the point of it?

Tags: ascii

I always wanted to ask this, I know that ASCII uses numbers to represent characters like 65 = A

Whats the point? computer understand when i press A is A why we need to convert to 65?

Comment: Computer doesn't necessarily understand when you press A. Check this out: https://github.com/alex/what-happens-when and https://www.futurelearn.com/info/courses/computer-systems/0/steps/53503. Unicode is likely used to map `A` from your keyboard to `A` on the screen.

Comment: You have it backwards: computers understand when you press an A *because of* codes like ASCII

Comment: Im reading days like all google result pages, but still cant understand, A is A why to be 65 no point

Comment: General note: these days ASCII is basically meaningless with Unicode (and its various encodings) being the more important concepts, but that doesn't fundamentally change the essence of your question: they both exist to solve the same basic problem.

Comment: Because everything in a computer is converted to numbers.  More specifically, everything in a computer is ones and zeroes.  Pick up a basic computer architecture book.

Answer (score 3):

You have it backwards: computers understand when you press an A *because of* codes like ASCII. Or rather, one part of the computer is able to tell another part of the computer that you pressed an A because they agree on conventions of binary signals like ASCII.

At its lowest level, each part of the computer "knows" that it is in one of two states - maybe off and on, maybe high voltage and low voltage, maybe two directions of magnetism, and so on. For convenience, we label these two states 0 and 1. We then build elaborate (and microscopic) sequences of machinery that each say "if this thing's a 1, then do this, if it's a 0 do this".

If we string a sequence of 1s and 0s together, we can write a number, like 1010; and we can make machinery that does maths with those numbers, like 1010 + 0001 = 1011. Alternatively, we can string a much longer sequence together to represent the brightness of pixels from the top left to bottom right of a screen, in order - a bitmap image. The computer doesn't "know" which sequences are numbers and which are images, we just tell it "draw the screen based on this sequence" and "calculate my wages based on this sequence".

If we want to represent not numbers or images, but text, we need to come up with a sequence of bits for each letter and symbol. It doesn't really matter *what* sequence we use, we just need to be consistent - we could say that 000001 is A, and as long as we remember that's what we chose, we can write programs that deal with text. ASCII is simply one of those mappings of sequences of bits to letters and symbols.

Note that A is not defined as "65" in ASCII, it's defined as the 7 bit sequence 1000001; it just happens that that's the same sequence of bits we generally use for the number 65. Note also that ASCII is a *very old* mapping, and almost never used directly in modern computers; it is however very *influential*, and a lot of more recent mappings are designed to use the same or similar sequences for the letters and symbols that it covers.

Comment: Yeah, i know all these things but still why ASCII?

Comment: @Inj3ct0r Possibly you wrote that comment before I added the last paragraph of the answer. If you've read it all and still don't understand, you'll need to find some way to rephrase your question.

Comment: @Inj3ct0r: if all the information that you could find on the internet **and** this answer combined still don't help you then you must indeed find another way to phrase your question or you won't be able to find any help. Simply speaking: without something like ASCII, how would you solve the problem of storing a character in a machine that can only ever store numbers and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you for your time guys, I should connect the dots and understand this concept. I appreciate it